# How to find the area of circle inside the rectangle?

Tags: geometry, built-in-symbols, intersection

Consider a circle located at the origin

```
circ[R_] := Circle[{0,0},R]
```

and an arbitrary rectangle

```
rect[x1_,y1_,x2_,y2_] := Rectangle[{x1,y1},{x2,y2}]
```

These figures somehow intersect each other. Could you please tell me how to calculate the fraction of the circle's area $\epsilon = S_{\text{intersection}}/\pi R^{2}$ inside the rectangle, assuming completely arbitrary relative positions (i.e., a circle is inside the rectangle, or the latter is shifted)?

My attempt follows [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241334/how-to-get-the-intersection-between-circle-and-rectangle):

```
rectangle = Rectangle[{1, 1}, {2, 2}];
circle = Circle[{0, 0}, 2];
Area[RegionIntersection[rectangle, circle]]
```

But it gives zero, maybe since `RegionIntersection` does not compute the 2D region, only a curve of the surface intersections (?).

Comment: `rectangle = Rectangle[{1, 1}, {2, 2}];
circle = Disk[{0, 0}, 2];
Area[RegionIntersection[rectangle, circle]]
`

Comment: use `Disk` instead of `Circle` if you want the area. Or use `ArcLength` instead of `Area` if you want the length of the length of the  arc.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Conversion of @kglr's and @cvgmt's comments into a community wiki answer (edited slightly for clarity):*

**@cvgmt:**

```
rectangle = Rectangle[{1, 1}, {2, 2}];
circle = Disk[{0, 0}, 2];
Area[RegionIntersection[rectangle, circle]]
```

**@kglr:**

use `Disk` instead of `Circle` if you want the area. Or use `ArcLength` instead of `Area` if you want the length of the arc.